# Como generar objetos con coordenadas (X, Y, Z) y ver estos objetos en vistas en 2D?

Tags: python, pyqt5

La idea es crear ramas (representadas por una línea entre dos nodos) con coordenadas (x,y,z) pudiendo dibujar en 2D en cualquier vista, ya sea vista(x,y), vista(z,x) o vista(z,y) y luego poder visualizar estos objetos en una vista en 3D.

He estado intentando con Python y PyQt5.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class CadWindowMdi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CadWindowMdi, self).__init__()
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.mdiArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.mdiArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiArea)
        # self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.subwindow = CadView(CadScene())
        # self.subwindow.setWindowTitle('CAD')
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.subwindow)
        self.setWindowTitle("NT")

    @property
    def scene(self):
        if self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow():
            return self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow().scene
    @property
    def view(self):
        if self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow():
            return self.mdiArea.activeSubWindow().view
```

Lo anterior es la ventana principal.
Lo siguiente es la vista de la escena.

```py
class CadView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(CadView, self).__init__(scene, parent)
        self.scaleFactor=1
        self.controlPress=False
        self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
```

Esta es la clase escena que alberga los elementos de dibujo.

```py
class CadScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CadScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSceneRect(-10000, -10000, 20000, 20000)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255), QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        self._edge_item = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            node = Node()
            node.setPos(event.scenePos())
            self.addItem(node)

            if self._edge_item:
                self._edge_item.dst = node
                self._edge_item = None
            else:
                self._edge_item = Edge()
                self._edge_item.src = node
                self.addItem(self._edge_item)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._edge_item:
            self._edge_item.p2 = event.scenePos()
        super(CadScene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

Lo que sigue son las clases de nodos y ramas para dibujar.

```py
class Node(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rect=QtCore.QRectF(-5, -5, 10, 10), parent=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__(rect, parent)
        self.edges = []
        self.setZValue(1)
        self.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

    def addEdge(self, edge):
        self.edges.append(edge)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedChange:
            self.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.green if value else QtCore.Qt.darkGray)
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            for edge in self.edges:
                edge.adjust()
        return super(Node, self).itemChange(change, value)

class Edge(QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Edge, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1.5))
        self._src = None
        self._dst = None

    @property
    def src(self):
        return self._src

    @src.setter
    def src(self, node):
        self._src = node
        self._src.addEdge(self)
        self.adjust()

    @property
    def dst(self):
        return self._dst

    @dst.setter
    def dst(self, node):
        self._dst = node
        self._dst.addEdge(self)
        self.adjust()

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return self.line().p1()

    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        line.setP1(p)
        self.setLine(line)

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return self.line().p2()

    @p2.setter
    def p2(self, p):
        line = self.line()
        line.setP2(p)
        self.setLine(line)

    def adjust(self):
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        if self.src:
            self.p1 = self.src.pos()
            self.p2 = self.src.pos()
        if self.dst:
            self.p2 = self.dst.pos()
```

Aquí se inicia la app.

```py
def getCAD():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CadWindowMdi()
    window.show()
    return window, app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window, app = getCAD()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Dejo un GIF para explicar de mejor manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]